# How to terminate a Google Cloud Build Pipeline properly?

Tags: google-cloud-build

A pipeline is automatically terminated when any step in pipeline exited with an error code greater than 0. After that the build process is marked as failed. So far so good.

For instance when the current branch is master after some steps such as build and test I want to process some extra steps like tag and deploy. When the current branch is not master these extra steps can be skipped.

One workaround is having a guard on each extra step, which asks for the current branch. But this seems to be inelegant.

How to break a pipeline with exit code 0?

Comment: Are you asking how to do conditional build?

Comment: Conditional as well as terminating command

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing 'out of box' yet from cloud builder.

Work arounds are adding if statements

```
[[ "$REPO_NAME" == "master" ]] && your_command_here
```

You're going to have to change the entrypoint to a bash shell for this to work